# How can I use s3 object names as inputs to an MRJob mapper, but not the s3 objects themselves?

Tags: python, mapreduce, boto, elastic-map-reduce, mrjob

I'm missing something obvious about Yelp's [mrjob job](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/) library. Setting up an MRJob class is almost trivially easy. Running it over a [file](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/quickstart.html) or stdin also so. But how can I change the input to the job from a file either locally or in s3, to, say, keys in an s3 bucket?

Something like this. Suppose I wanted to count all objects in my S3 bucket that start with the string 'foo':

```
import re

class MRCountS3Objects(MRJob):

    define mapper(self, _, botoS3Key):
        if re.match('^foo', botoS3Key.name):
            yield 'foo', 1

    define reduce(self, name, occurrences):
        yield name, sum(occurrences)
```

It's a highly contrived example, but you probably get my drift. How can I tell MRJob to operate over a stream of s3 objects, ignoring the content of the objects? I saw the S3Filesystem.get_s3_keys() [method](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/runners-emr.html?highlight=s3#mrjob.emr.S3Filesystem.get_s3_keys), which gets me exactly the stream I need, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured at least one way to accomplish this. Your MRJob has a `stdin` attribute that can be assigned to any iterator, and then you can run the job programmatically. This code, for example, should work over `my-bucket`'s key names:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.emr import EMRJobRunner

class MRS3KeyProcessor(MRJob):
    # Do some MRJob stuff.
    ...

def s3_name_generator(bucket):
    """Generator that returns boto.s3.Key names.
    """
    # Could also use raw boto here.
    emr = EMRJobRunner()
    key_stream = emr.fs.get_s3_keys(bucket)
    for key in key_stream:
        yield key.name

def main():
    # The '-' argument signifies that we use stdin.
    mr_job = MRCountS3Objects(['--runner', 'inline', '-'])
    stdin = s3_name_generator('my-bucket')
    mr_job.stdin = stdin
    results = []
    with mr_job.make_runner() as runner:
        runner.run()
        for line in runner.stream_output():
            key, value = mr_job.parse_output_line(line)
            results.append((key, value))
    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```